# Number as icon of notification Android

Tags: java, android, icons

my problem seems be without (smart) solution... please help

I'm working on app that update a persistent notification with temp and weather description.

The problem is that I want show current temp in notification bar but

```
mNotification = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
    .setTicker(number);
```

this code show but with auto-hide, the only value data still persist in bar it's smallIcon.

The problem is that setSmallIcon() want a resource (int) to work, this is carzy, there are other options?

I don't want put inside app 100 or more little images with number, it's no sense...

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible according to the current android notification design principle. You are only allowed to add text in the notification area/status bar.

Comment: Ok, I think that there aren't any option to fix text in title bar? (by default text desapear after few ms)

Comment: Ok, I know, by .setOngoing(true) but I can make permanent ticker too?

Comment: This is useless, I did read it, the point isn't make permanent notification (that I did) but show info in title bar (in this case temp). I make some icon to test with a switch based on number but are too small